# Redirecting to Last page in case of successful edit only

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Since whole a day I have been trying to search for best solution to redirect to same page where it is requested. Means I have a edit action page. I can move on this page from anywhere either it is detail, view, latest, recent or from any other action I can move to edit action. What I want is I want to move to last action again where it is redirected from. While googling I got solution to put

```
`$this->redirect($this->referer());` //or 
`$this->redirect(Controller::referer());`
```

to use in controller to move to but it reverts to edit page again as it is navigated from that only.

Other solution told me to use hidden variable whose value it

```
`echo $this->Form->input('Song.referer', array('type' => 'text', "value"=>$this->request->referer()));`
```

like this and request to this variable on successfull edit that is OK. But it fails in case of validation put on controller as same page is open in case of error so my referer change. What shall be best practise in this case. Should I save session in and every call to main my referrer or something other available with cakephp 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the last location in hidden field eg.

```
$this->request->data["Business"]["referer"] = $this->referer();
```

Now put optional condition on save function to redirect on the page like this.

```
if ($this->Business->save($this->request->data)) {
    (isset($this->request->data["Business"]["referer"]) && !empty($this->request->data["Business"]["referer"]) ? $this->redirect($this->request->data["Business"]["referer"]) : $this->redirect(array("action" => "index"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

when I create a link to my edit page in my action i add a 'referer' param

```
$this->Html->link('Add', array('action' => 'add', 'referer' => 'detail'));
```

in my controller then I read the value of referer and i redirect to the right page after saving the data, even in case of validation error the value of referer remains in the url of the page

It's not a great solution since it's not transparent to the user who see the url and can change the referer changing the url itself. But it works and it's simple to implement

Comment: Not a perfect solution. Don't know why but I couldn't implement it.

Comment: You are doing for simple button that can also be done using `Javascript:history.go(-1);`